# How can I generate translation files if the kendo-ui uses English expressions by default but I'm using another language in my app?

Tags: angular, internationalization, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm trying to integrate i18n to my angular7 application. It uses kendo-ui too.
Kendo-ui templates contains English expressions, but my app code contains Hungarian expressions.
If I generate the `messages.xlf` file with the `ng xi18n --output-path translate`, the generated file will contain the English expressions from kendo-ui and the Hungarian expressions from my app.

What could be the proper way to generate the `messages.xlf`?

Comment: Have you tried ngx-translate (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-translate/core)? It is very easy to use

Comment: Yes, I've tried. And it is the current solution inside my app code.

But the kendo-ui needed i18n so I thought that would be great if I could use the same technique in my app code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong because not necessary to use angular i18n for Kenod-UI translations.
The `MessageService` was perfect for me: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/globalization/localization/messages/#toc-using-the-message-service

So I kept the original ngx-translate solution in my app code and I've added a new provider (the implementation of MessageService) which resolves the translations from Kendo-UI.

This is the code of my MessagesService:

```
export class KendoMessageService extends MessageService {
  constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {}

  public get(key: string): string {
    const resolvedValue = this.translateService.instant(key);
    return resolvedValue !== key ? resolvedValue : void 0;
  }
}
```